# Add to the last digit a number

Tags: replacement

I have data from a Multimeter that has a precision of 0.6%rdg+4dgt. So i want to take the last digit of, say, `12.007` and add 4 to the last digit like `12.011`.
I'm doing `RealDigits[12.007,10,5][[1,-1]]`add 4 and then somehow with`FromDigits` get the result...it seems trivial but i don't see how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
ClearAll[func];
func[add_, pos_: (-1)] :=  N@FromDigits@MapAt[# + add &, RealDigits[##], {{1, pos}}] &

func[4, -1][12.007, 10, 5]
(* 12.011` *)
func[4, -3][12.707, 10, 5]
(* 13.107` *)
```

Comment: it works fine but i want to use it in a rule like `{a_,b_}->{a,fun[4,-1]@b}`but it seems that first apply the function to a and then the substitution rule.

Comment: @Kafkarudo, can you give an example for the list you are trying to transform? Btw, perhaps you need `:>` instead of `->`?

Comment: yep, the :> did it! thank a lot.